# Bootstrap 3.1.1: how to use its RTL?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, boot

Today, I downloaded Bootstrap **3.1.1** at https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap

I notice that under its directory

/dist/css

I see the following file:

bootstrap-rtl.css

I assume that this file is for RTL.

However, in this blog: http://blog.getbootstrap.com/, I see the following:

**While we originally wanted v3.1 to include RTL support, we decided to hold back on that for some potentially beneficial unreleased tooling. We'll share more on that when we know more, but suffice to say it's been bumped to **v3.2**.**

Am I supposed to use this bootstrap-rtl.css in **3.1.1** for a RTL website? What is its development status? I am unable to see any javascript files for RTL in the download (or use the same bootstrap.js for both LTR and RTL websites?).

I am  confused. Is there any tutorial about how to use it? I googled and failed to find any tutorial about it.

Comment: Did you try asking to @twbootstrap via Twitter?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning. I don't do twitter. This is a programming-related question and I hope to hear from some of the many experts at SO.

Comment: You're welcome. Just wanted to let you know that @twbootstrap is the official Twitter account of Bootstrap team and you could probably get a more satisfactory answer from them.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's BETA or ALPHA version, I use it in Wordpress Theme development and it's good in my usage. for example in it's grid system 's sorts by floating right.

Comment: Ehsan, thanks so much for your input. For this to work, do you need separate boostrap.js for RTL? I dont see it come with v3.1.1. I have been using another tool for RTL https://github.com/jnaqsh/rbootstrap. It has corresponding javascript file.